# AsyncTask gets sometimes not executed in Android 2.1

Tags: android, android-asynctask

i have an AsyncTask that gets executed when the app starts up. on a galaxy S with android 2.1 on it, this AsyncTaks gets not always executed. i realize that there is a max of 5 AsyncTaks that can be running at the same time, but i actually assumed that this is per app and because this one is executed on the app startup i am certain that there are no other ones running at this point.

is there a way to check if the AsyncTask can be executed at this time or to increase the maximum number of running AsyncTasks or anything that might help me with that problem?

the AsyncTask itself is very simple and gets executed in the UI thread

```
new AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void>(){
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Integer... arg0) {
    …
    return null;
}

protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    …
}
}.execute(myVal);
```

thanks
Simon

Comment: are you sure it's not executed? add `Log.d(TAG, "message")` to your overriden methods of AsyncTask to make sure it really is not executed.

Comment: are you creating a new AsynTask whenever you want to execute?

Comment: yes i am creating a new AsyncTask instance every time when it is supposed to run. and yes, i am sure it does not get executed. in addition to the log, i also tried to debug it and it did not stop at the breakpoint.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

OK, i've got it. there were some old AsyncTasks from previous app starts that got somehow stuck.